# How To Use EssentialAction

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a custom body parser that streams the request body to an Amazon S3 instance and I want to do validation prior to uploading the file.

In the headers of the request I have access to the content size and the user's auth token. With these two things, I can validate that the user has permission to upload the file.

After reading Play!'s documentation, it seems that [`EssentialAction`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/HttpApi) or [`Action Composition`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaActionsComposition) is the way to go.

Here is my controller method without any decoration:

```
def upload = Action(streamingBodyParser(streamConstructor)) { request =>
   ...
}
```

I've tried creating a custom essential action and using that before my body parsing action but I couldn't quite get the syntax right:

```
class HasEnoughSpace(action: EssentialAction) extends EssentialAction {
  override def apply(request: RequestHeader): EssentialAction = {
    val maybeToken = request.headers.get("X-Auth-Token")
    maybeToken match {
      case Some(t) => {

      }
      case _ => 
    }
  }
}

def upload = HasEnoughSpace { Action(streamingBodyParser(streamConstructor)) { request => 
  ...
}
```

I also tried using the new ActionBuilder method but that still parsed the body prior to allowing me to do validation.

Is there a way to accomplish this with EssentialAction? Is there a better way to accomplish my goal of validating the headers prior to parsing the body?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly what EssentialAction is meant to be used for. It enables you to inspect the request header, but ignoring the body, what should be sufficient for your case.
EssentialActions are bascially just functions taking a RequestHeader and returning an Iteratee[Array[Byte], Result]:

```
trait EssentialAction extends (RequestHeader => Iteratee[Array[Byte], Result]) with Handler
```

Therefore it would be easier if you rewrite your HasEnoughSpace action to be a function that creates an EssentialAction instead of trying to extend the EssentialAction trait:

```
 def HasEnoughSpace(action: EssentialAction): EssentialAction =  EssentialAction { request =>
      val token = request.headers.get("X-Auth-Token")
      val contentSize = request.headers.get(play.api.http.HeaderNames.CONTENT_LENGTH)
      (token, contentSize) match {
        // perform validation if both headers are present
        case (Some(_), Some(len)) if validateContentLength(len) => {
          action(request)
        }
        case _ =>
          // replace with your client error
          Done(Unauthorized("401 No Token\n"))
      }
    }
```

In the above code you'd still need to write the validateContentLength function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will check this out as soon as I get home from work.

Comment: `Accumulator.done` instead of `Done` works for me in Play 2.6.