# How can an action convey that it has no body using a type?

Tags: scala, playframework

An action in the controller have a type Action[A], which means that the body is an A (i.e should parse to A).

I'd like to look at an action's signature and know if it has no body, which is useful for GET requests for example.
e.g here's a code example with two actions, one that accepts a Person in the body and one that does not have a body:

```scala
case class Person(name: String)
implicit val personFormats: Format[Person] = Json.format[Person]
val people: mutable.Set[Person] = mutable.Set(Person("alice"), Person("bob"))

/** here it is clear that the body should contain a person info, since the method returns `Action[Person]` */
def createPerson(): Action[Person] =
  Action(parse.json[Person]) { request: Request[Person] =>
    val person: Person = request.body
    if (people.add(person))
      Ok(s"added ${person.name}")
    else
      Ok(s"${person.name} is already there :) nothing special to do")
  }

/** Can it be clearer from the signature that there's no body? */
def findPerson(name: String): Action[AnyContent] =
  Action {
    people.find(_.name == name) match {
      case Some(person) => Ok(Json.toJson(person))
      case None => NotFound(s"no person named $name")
    }
}
```

When I look at the body of the second action, `findPerson`, it is clear from `Action(parse.empty)` that the body is empty.
How can it be clear from the signature as well without messing up the body?

Returning `Action[AnyContentAsEmpty]` cannot work because `play.api.mvc.AnyContentAsEmpty` is an object.

There's the following version, where we pass `parse.empty` as the parser, and it would work, but `request` is unused, and I wonder if there's another way:

```scala
def findPerson2(name: String): Action[Unit] =
    Action(parse.empty) { request =>
      people.find(_.name == name) match {
        case Some(person) => Ok(Json.toJson(person))
        case None => NotFound(s"no person named $name")
      }
    }
```

Comment: Honestly the fact that you're not using an `implicit request` would be enough for me to tell that you're not using a body, if I were to read this. Or write a scaladoc for your function.

Comment: i agree. i just wondered if it can be expressed in the type system

Answer (score 1):

Consider [`EssentialAction`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27364111/5205022) which by-design does not have a body parser like so

```
def findPerson(name: String) = 
  EssentialAction { _ =>
    people.find(_.name == name) match {
      case Some(person) => Accumulator.done(Ok(Json.toJson(person)))
      case None => Accumulator.done(NotFound(s"no person named $name"))
    }
}
```

or [`ActionBuilder.IgnoringBody()`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/b6aaab6fb4908f19f94a4fc39f87a58b01a43608/core/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Action.scala#L421) like so

```
val ignoringBodyAction = new ActionBuilder.IgnoringBody()(executionContext)
def findPerson(name: String) =
  ignoringBodyAction {
    people.find(_.name == name) match {
      case Some(person) => Ok(Json.toJson(person))
      case None => NotFound(s"no person named $name")
    }
}
```

Comment: it is a matter of taste, but the `EssentialAction` option messes up the implementation more than i wanted.
The `IgnoringBody` option is neat, but the result type is still `Action[AnyContent]`.
i'll probably stick to `def findPerson(name: String): Action[Unit] = Action(parse.empty) { _ => /* .. */`.
thanks